# Getting [object HTMLInputElement] in display instead of number

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, function

I am taking a number as an input from an input box and on clicking a button, I want the number to be displayed on the page. But I am getting, `[object HTMLInputElement]`  as the output.

Here's my typescript code:

```
let quantity = <HTMLInputElement>document.createElement("input");
quantity.type = "number"
quantity.id = "quan"
document.body.appendChild(quantity)

var getQuantity = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("quan");
let gq = getQuantity.toString()

var btn = <HTMLButtonElement>document.createElement("button");
document.body.appendChild(btn)

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    Display.innerHTML += "<br>"+ gq
})
```

Comment: check this - getQuantity.value instead of getQuantity.toString()

Comment: Also, try addiing more details of your code.

Comment: @TusharShahi, More details as in?

Comment: Since quantity is an important variable in your code, you could show its initialization/declaration.  But your question is answered for now, so it does not matter.

Comment: yes, I had missed it out. quantity was created using create element. I will make sure to be more clear from next time onwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `.toString()`, you get the string representation of the Input Element.

You want the value, so you can just call `.value`. In your example that would look like so:

```js
let gq = getQuantity.value;
```